# How to include docker cookbook in chef?

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf

I'm trying to define a chef recipe to install docker using the cookbook provided at this link: https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/docker#readme

I'm using Berkshelf so I put this line on Berkfile

```
cookbook 'docker', '~> 2.9.6'
```

and this on the metadata.db

```
depends "docker"
```

My recipe is the following

```
include_recipe 'docker::docker_service'
include_recipe 'docker::docker_image'
include_recipe 'docker::docker_container'

docker_service 'default' do
        action [:create, :start]
end
```

but when I try to run the kitchen I obtain the following error:

```
ERROR: could not find recipe docker_service for cookbook docker
```

but if I look in my berkshelf repository the recipe is there:

```
$ ls ~/.berkshelf/cookbooks/docker-2.9.6/libraries/ | grep docker_service.rb
docker_service.rb
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Michele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docker cookbook does not provide any recipes, which is why your `include_recipe` calls fail.

Instead, you just use the resources, like you already have with the `docker_service` resource.

Your recipe should run when you delete your three `include_recipe` lines.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't undestand it. After removing the the lines it worked.

Answer (score 4):

As stated by @coderanger and @NilsLandt you need to write your own cookbook to install docker and just call the resources provided by the [docker](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/docker) cookbook.

## Example

Sample cookbook generated by the "chef generate cookbook" command

```
├── Berksfile
├── chefignore
├── metadata.rb
├── README.md
├── recipes
│   └── default.rb
└── test
    └── integration
        ├── default
        │   └── serverspec
        │       └── default_spec.rb
        └── helpers
            └── serverspec
                └── spec_helper.rb
```

### metadata.rb

Add the "apt" and "docker" cookbooks as dependencies

```
name 'docker_demo'
maintainer 'Mark O''Connor'
maintainer_email 'you@example.com'
license 'all_rights'
description 'Installs/Configures docker_demo'
long_description 'Installs/Configures docker_demo'
version '0.1.0'

depends 'apt'
depends 'docker'
```

### recipes/default.rb

Just use the "docker_service" resource to create a docker service. The "create" action will install Docker.

```
#
# Cookbook Name:: docker_demo
# Recipe:: default
#
# Copyright (c) 2016 The Authors, All Rights Reserved.

include_recipe 'apt'

docker_service 'default' do
  action [:create, :start]
end
```

### test/integration/default/serverspec/default_spec.rb

A set of tests to verify the installation of docker

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe file('/usr/bin/docker') do
  it { should be_file }
  it { should be_executable }
end

describe command('/usr/bin/docker version') do
  its(:stdout) { should match /Version:      1.12.1/ }
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful, especially the test part.

Answer (score 1):

`docker_service` is a resource, not a recipe. See the readme for some example usage, but the overall idea is you need to write your own wrapper cookbook which uses the custom resources provided.